# Software to group c# class members

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there some software for visual studio to automatically group c# class members?

Comment: Please clarify. Do you mean something that will reorder things and put #region tags around groups of similar items?

Comment: Sure that or any other way of grouping. That is why I didn't clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does that, amongst loads of other things.

Comment: +1 for ReSharper as a generally awesome tool.  I really dislike using Visual Studio without it.

Comment: The ReSharper member ordering/grouping is completely configurable too.

Comment: I have ReSharper now. I ran code cleanup. Can it group type members in regions?

Answer (score 0):

[Regionerate](http://www.rauchy.net/regionerate/) can do that, and I think [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) too (not sure). Both Visual Studio add-ons are free.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this plugin for Visual Studio that displays a grouped view. You can choose what groupings to apply, what order they're applied in, and write your own.

http://ora.codeplex.com/

It has some issues if you ever use VB.NET, but some people have posted workarounds.

If you have a live-updated view like this, you don't need to manually maintain the ordering in the file, or spread a lot of silly nested regions around in your source. Regions (like comments) shouldn't be used to redundantly repeat information that is already in the code. It just gets out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.usysware.com/dpack/

DPack includes various browser tools that allow the developer to quickly find solution files, types, particular type members, methods or properties for instance, or quickly find and reference standard .NET framework types.